# Convert unconventional datetime string to POSIXct in R

Tags: r, datetime, datetime-format, lubridate, posixct

What format string argument of the `as.POSIXct()` function would allow me to coerce the following timestamp into POSIXct?

```
datetime <- "2018/02/08T23:58:33z"
datetime <- as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC)
```

Desired result

```
2018-02-08 23:58:33
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just put a literal "T" in the string to match (trailing characters are ignored by default anyway):

```
as.POSIXct(datetime, format = "%Y/%m/%dT%H:%M:%S", tz = "UTC")
```

Comment: If you have fractional seconds and want to keep that info, try `"%Y/%m/%dT%H:%M:%OSz"`

Answer (score 1):

Other option is to use `anytime` which parses automatically

```
anytime::anytime(datetime, tz = "UTC", asUTC = TRUE)
#[1] "2018-02-08 23:58:33 UTC"
```

Comment: Thanks for the input! I’ve never used anytime before!